# Matching text between a pair of single quotes

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract a ImageNet labels from the .txt file that is presented as follows.

```
998: 'ear, spike, capitulum',
999: 'toilet tissue, toilet paper, bathroom tissue'}
```

I've tried

```
label = []

txt = open("imagenet1000_clsid_to_human.txt").readlines()
#  print(str(txt))
p = re.compile(r"'(.*?)'")

#  print(txt)
for i in range(len(txt)):
    #  print(txt[i])
    #  print('\n')
    m = p.match(txt[i])

    if m:
        lis = list(m.group())[:-1]
        s = ''.join(lis)
        print(s)
        label.append(s)
```

to extract the substring inside the single quotation marks, but it continuously spits out 'None'.

I've tried in online regex compiler, and it worked perfectly fine. Can anybody give some advice for this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but still not working...

Comment: you need to escape special character in regex. use \'

Comment: Look at the function findall in the re package.

Comment: Well, I haven't show all my .txt files, but it consists of multiple lines!

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry, misread your post. I’ll edit my answer - findall is still what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :D!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you should be using `re.search()`, not `re.match()`.  `re.match()` matches the pattern starting at the start of the string, there is an implied `^` at the start of the pattern.

It is wise to use a raw string for RE patterns, and you have overdone the brackets:

```
import re

txt = "998: 'ear, spike, capitulum', 999: 'toilet tissue, toilet paper, bathroom tissue'"

p = re.compile(r"'(.*?)'")
m = p.search(txt)
print(m.groups())
```

Gives:

```
('ear, spike, capitulum',)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import re
re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", txt)
```

This regex link:

https://regex101.com/r/QP8omt/1

Answer (score 0):

Not everything needs to be done through regex.

```
label = []

with open("imagenet1000_clsid_to_human.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split("'")
        if len(parts) == 3:
            label.append(parts[1])
```

Side note: Always open text files with a specific encoding. If you are unsure what encoding the file is, then so is Python. There is no magic encoding detection and you should not rely on Python's defaults.

Comment: Thanks! But where did `len(parts) == 3` came from?

Comment: I inserted that to make sure that only lines are considered that contain exactly two single quotes, i.e. exactly 3 parts after splitting.

Comment: Got it! Thanks :D